# What is the law with eating the third Shabbos meal when the first day of Pesach is Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, passover, meal-seudah, matzah

This year the first day of Pesach is Shabbos.
There is an obligation to eat a third meal.
It seem that there may be two issues: see [here](http://www.halachayomit.co.il/DisplayRead.asp?readID=219)

Eating a third meal may take away the appetite for matzoh at the seder, 
and normally we do not allow matzoh to be eaten after noon before the (first) seder.

This problem is discussed widely when Erev Pesach falls on Shabbos ([see eg this article from OU](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_seudah_shelishit/)) but not so widely when  the first day of Pesach is Shabbos.

Comment: Simple solution: move to Israel, where we only have one seder!

Comment: Possible correction? I assume that when reciting the halacha, you said, "we do not allow matzoh to be eaten after noon before the (first) seder". I see that you put "first" in parentheses. This year Se'udah Shlishit is before the 2nd Seder. AFAIK, the halachot should be the same, but, perhaps, not (regardless of the fact that it is Shabbat). My reasoning is that during Yom Tov, it is a mitzvah to eat, and, I don't think there is a problem of eating matzot after noon on the 1st day of Yom Tov as long as you don't stuff yourself so that you won't enjoy the seder Matzah? Can u confirm?

Comment: "normally we do not allow matzoh to be eaten after noon before the (first) seder" We don't allow Matza to be eaten ALL DAY before the first seder. Clearly we don't worry about that before the second seder, or we couldn't have lunch.

Answer (score 1):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קג - דיני שמחת יום טוב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0102_L2) says that the first day of Yom Tov is always treated as an *Erev Yom Tov*:

> אֵיזֶהוּ כִּבּוּד. זֶה שֶׁאָמְרוּ רַבּוֹתֵינוּ זִכְרוֹנָם לִבְרָכָה, שֶׁמִּצְוָה עַל הָאָדָם לְגַלֵּחַ בְּעֶרֶב יוֹם טוֹב, כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא יִכָּנֵס לָרֶגֶל כְּשֶׁהוּא מְנֻוָּל. וְכֵן מִצְוָה לִרְחוֹץ בְּחַמִּין וְלָחֹף רֹאשׁוֹ וְלִטּוֹל צִפָּרְנָיו בְּעֶרֶב יוֹם טוֹב, כְּמוֹ בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת. וְכֵן מִצְוָה לָלוּשׁ פַּת בְּבֵיתוֹ בְּעֶרֶב יוֹם טוֹב לִכְבוֹד יוֹם טוֹב כְּמוֹ בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת. וְכֵן אָסוּר לֶאֱכוֹל בְּעֶרֶב יוֹם טוֹב מִן הַמִּנְחָה וּלְמַעְלָה כְּמוֹ בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת, כְּדֵי שֶׁיֹּאכַל סְעוּדַּת יוֹם טוֹב לְתֵאָבוֹן. וְ**אִם חָל עֶרֶב יוֹם טוֹב בַּשַׁבָּת, יֹאכַל סְעוּדָּה שְׁלִישִׁית קֹדֶם מִנְחָה קְטַנָּה. וְכֵן הַדִּין בְּיוֹם טוֹב רִאשׁוֹן שֶׁהוּא עֶרֶב יוֹם טוֹב שֵׁנִי**. ‏

As a result, one has to eat the 3rd Shabbat meal before Mincha-time. That's 2½ *Halachic* hours before sunset.

Comment: It's 2.5 Halachic hours before sunset isn't it? [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 69:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93_-_%D7%A1%D7%98)  But how do you know that you can eat matzoh at this time?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%90_%D7%91