# Eating matzah on the second day of erev Pesach

Tags: passover, derabanan, matzah

I don't have all the sources and grounding for the various suppositions I am going to present so I apologize -- I fear I can't put this question into proper words:

We refrain from eating matzah (at [least](https://www.aish.com/atr/Last_Chance_for_Matzah.html)) on the day time before the seder so that the matzah can be eaten with the proper appetite.

The mitzvot of the second day of yom tov must be kept and in fact (according to the [Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/708510/jewish/Laws-of-Yom-Tov.htm#footnote2a708510) website) "it was decided that we must be just as strict on all matters on the second days as on the first".

The [obligation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36507/why-do-we-make-blessings-on-mitzvot-drabbanan-at-the-second-seder) of second yom tov can even [outweigh](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Second_Day_of_Yom_Tov#cite_note-7) a daily, required Torah level obligation.

If these are all the case, then how can we be required to eat matzah during the day on the first full day of Yom Tov if it would mean not eating matzah with the same appetite during the [second seder](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/why-do-we-say-pesach-seder-brachot-both-nights)? We should at least be required to stop eating matzah by the same time that we stopped eating it on erev Pesach.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56923/what-is-the-law-with-eating-the-third-shabbos-meal-when-the-first-day-of-pesach#comment151787_56923 This is sort of analogous to sitting in the Sukkah on Shmini Atzeret: trouble applying rules of Erev Yom Tov to Yom Tov Rishon.

Comment: Not sure that second day of erev Pesach is the best way to describe this

Comment: @DoubleAA First day of Pesach?

Comment: @DoubleAA Erev the second day of Pesach?

Comment: None of those appear to do it justice since they all apply in Israel. Outside of Israel we regularly have "second day" of one day events. This is no different, at least in the have amina. The whole point of the question is that Erev Pesach prohibitions should be observed for two days our of doubt! (rosends youre of course welcome to change it but I thought you'd like it)

Comment: The evening in question is often referred to as the "second night of Pesach" in less religious circles....in this case I think that may be the best possible term

Comment: @josh the q is about a daytime period, not an evening

Comment: This is a "gemarah kopp" type question, and I can't quite argue against your reasoning, here. However, there is an opinion that says that even though one is not required to eat matzot outside the 1st (or 1st and 2nd) nights, one gains a mitzvah by doing so. Thus, at least during the daytime of the 1st day, there is a "cross over" of concepts.